# Can anyone tell me the what 「propose」,「writeBlock」,「StoreBlock」，「Validate」「commit」stage means in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Here is the log of Hyperledger Fabric test network. There are 2 peer node(peer0.org1.example.com & peer0.org2.example.com) and 2 orderer node(orderer.example.com & orderer2.example.com).

My question is what 「writeBlock」,「StoreBlock」，「Validate」「commit」stage actually does? I know that at 「propose」stage, a chosen orderer(in this case, orderer.example.com) will create a block and then send the created block to other orderer such as orderer2.example.com. However, I don't understand what orderers does at「writeBlock」stage. Do they sign the created block at 「writeBlock」stage? Next, peer nodes received the block from who? orderer.example.com or orderer2.example.com? In my guess, I think it's from orderer.example.com but I'm not sure. [image]

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand what orderers does at「writeBlock」stage.

I'm not sure about those stages (writeBlock looks self-explanatory). I don't know about "StoreBlock", it isn't mentioned in the official docs. I'm wondering which Fabric version you are using.

> Next, peer nodes received the block from who?

In a RAFT network you have a leader/follower model. You can think of a leader peer as an entry point/doorman for all communication coming from the ordering nodes. An ordering node sends blocks to the leading peer(s) of each organization; the leading peer is then responsible for distributing those blocks to other peers belonging to the same organization. Distribution is done using gossip protocol.

Comment: I am using Fabric version 2.2. What does exactly commit stage does? In my understanding, at StoreBlock stage, the peer simply receive the unvalidated block and the commit stage is when the block is finalized(through validate stage) and it will be permanent in blockchain. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric is a complex system, with many components and a lot of moving parts.
The log that you are referring to is the log of the orderer node - orderer.example.com. It's a part of the Fabric test network. You can see what's happening in detail by looking at the logs of other Fabric components, such as peer node logs.

The Fabric network has a set of orderer nodes, which are responsible for ordering the transactions and creating blocks in the blockchain.
The orderer nodes are configured to use a consensus algorithm (such as Solo or Kafka) to achieve a consensus about the order of the transactions.
A Fabric network has a set of peer nodes, which are responsible for executing the chaincode (smart contracts) and catching and validating the transactions.

The Fabric test network consists of one orderer node, which is configured to use Solo consensus algorithm. This orderer node is orderer.example.com.
The Fabric test network consists of two peer nodes, which are peer0.org1.example.com and peer0.org2.example.com.

The log that you are referring to is the log of the orderer node - ord